# Encoding/Decoding

Tags: swift, nscoding

I'm trying to encode some class properties according to the NSCoding protocol:

```
 func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder){
      // a Date
      aCoder.encode(startDate, forKey: "startDate");
      // a ()->()
      aCoder.encode(handler, forKey: "handler");   //1
      // a Boolean
      aCoder.encode(rightAway, forKey: "rightAway");
 }
```

I've isolated the problem to be on the line marked with 1. If i comment that line, everything runs okay. If i do run that line as well, i get `unrecognized selector`. Is there any special care to take when encoding closures? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You get `unrecognized selector` error in both lines because neither `Timer` nor a Swift closure conform to `NSCoding`. An object conforming to the protocol must be inherit from `NSObject` (which a Swift closure doesn't anyway) and implement `init(coder` and `encode(with:)`

Why do you want to encode both? A `Timer` is an complex class and can easily be recreated and a closure is a function which actually does not contain any valuable data.

PS: Remove the trailing semicolons. This is not Objective-C

Comment: Yeah, indeed was not intended (typo). I've edited the original post.  I can rebuild the timer, but what about the closure? I have a class that needs to be passed a function to operate and when restored, i would still need that function. How would i go to solve this?

Comment: You can't store a closure... That would require you to store the entire state of the application. What does the closure you are trying to restore do?